# How to accept physical location alert in IE

Tags: selenium-webdriver, iedriverserver

In my project I am getting the below alert in IE after navigating to the Location tab.

[image]

Now I would like to accept the same and for that I had added the below capabilities but it is not working.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver",properties.getProperty("InternetExplorerDriverPath"));
DesiredCapabilities ieCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
ieCapabilities.setCapability("nativeEvents", true);
ieCapabilities.setCapability("window.confirm", true);
ieCapabilities.setCapability("unexpectedAlertBehaviour", "accept");
ieCapabilities.setCapability("disable-popup-blocking", true);
ieCapabilities.setCapability("enablePersistentHover", true);
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieCapabilities);
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unable to open the url. In such cases in IE browser, `ALT+N` command will shift the focus to the alert pop up in the bottom of the page.
So, you can use a `Robot` class and send `ALT+N` keys to shift the focus to the alert pop up and then you can pass `TAB` keys and select the required options (i.e. to Allow Once or select other options).

Sample Example:

```
    Robot robo=new Robot();
    robo.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
    robo.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_N); //this will move the focus to alert pop up
    //play around with other keys once the foucs moves to the alert pop up
    //ensure to release all the keys
```

Note: Check if `ALT+N` command shifts the focus to the alert pop up manually and then try using selenium